# PHP syntax error, unexpected 'prefix' (T_STRING), expecting ']'

Tags: php, laravel, routes

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'portfolio'],function() {
```

This is the line where I found my problem. what is bad here ?. I'm using laravel 5.6 and this is my directory …\routes\web.php39

Comment: What version of php do you use?

Comment: Hi. Please put more lines (or the whole route file content) here. I think the main problem is before this line.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-groups)

Comment: Can you show a few lines before and a few lines after?

Comment: Please put whole code block till the closing brace of the 'function() {'

Comment: it would help to post the whole `web.php` file.

Comment: Route::prefix('portfolio')->group(function () {
  
  Route::get('/',['uses'=>'PortfolioController@execute','as'=>'portfolio']);
  
  Route::match(['get','post'],'/add',['uses'=>'PortfolioAddController@execute','as'=>'portfolioAdd']);
  
  Route::match(['get','post','delete'],'/edit/(portfolio)',['uses'=>'PortfolioEditController@execute','as'=>'portfolioEdit]);
  
 });

Answer (score 0):

change to this

```
Route::prefix('portfolio')->group(function () {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-groups) your grouped routes should look like this:

```
Route::prefix('portfolio')->group(function () {
    Route::get('users', function () {
        // Matches The "/portfolio/users" URL
    });
});
```

Replace the `users` route with any route you want prefixed.

Comment: OP's problem is related to a syntax error... not misuse of the framework.

Answer (score -2):

**You are using wrong structure to add prefix:**

**Use below structure**

```
Route::prefix('portfolio')->group(function() {
    //your routes here
});
```

Laravel 5.5 has intrduced some methods like `prefix`, `middleware`, `namespace` and `name` etc so that we can chain features and requirements on routes.

**You can chain them like below**

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'admin.auth'])
     ->namespace('Admin')
     ->prefix('admin')
     ->name('admin.')
     ->group(function() {
         //your routes here
});
```

Comment: I don't see any difference.

Comment: does the OP? or the code is just incomplete?

Comment: I think he just posted the first line, not the whole thing.

Comment: Missing `)` wouldn't cause this error.

Comment: You guys were right. I have updated my answer